# How to use imported function from a module that creates and returns a DAG for UI to see?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I've created a module named `dag_template_module.py` that returns a DAG using specified arguments. I want to use this definition for multiple DAGs, doing same thing but from different sources (thus parameters). A simplified version of `dag_template_module.py`:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

def dag_template(
    dag_id: str,
    echo_message_1: str,
    echo_message_2: str
):
    @dag(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    schedule_interval="0 6 2 * *"
    )
    def dag_example():

        echo_1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='echo_1',
            bash_command=f'echo {echo_message_1}'
        )

        echo_2 = BashOperator(
            task_id='echo_2',
            bash_command=f'echo {echo_message_2}'
        )

        echo_1 >> echo_2

    dag = dag_example()

    return dag
```

Now I've created a `hello_world_dag.py` that imports `dag_template()` function from `dag_template_module.py` and uses it to create a DAG:

```
from dag_template import dag_template

hello_world_dag = dag_template(
    dag_id='hello_world_dag',
    echo_message_1='Hello',
    echo_message_2='World'
)
```

I've expected that this DAG will be discovered by Airflow UI but that's not the case.

I've also tried using `globals()` in `hello_world_dag.py` according to [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#how-to-create-dags-dynamically) but that also doesn't work for me:

```
from dag_template import dag_template

hello_world_dag = 'hello_word_dag'
globals()[hello_world_dag] = dag_template(dag_id='hello_world_dag',
                                          echo_message_1='Hello',
                                          echo_message_2='World'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

- The DAG you are attempting to create is missing the `start_date` param
- There is a nuance to how Airflow determine which Python files *might* contain a DAG definition and it's [looking for "dag" and "airflow" in the file contents](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fa2bec042995004f45b914dd1d66b466ccced410/airflow/utils/file.py#L338). The `hello_world_dag.py` is missing these keywords so the DagFileProcessor won't attempt to parse this file and, therefore, doesn't call the `dag_template()` function.

Adding these small tweaks, and running with Airflow 2.5.0:

**dag_template_module.py**

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


def dag_template(dag_id: str, echo_message_1: str, echo_message_2: str):
    @dag(dag_id, start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 22), schedule=None)
    def dag_example():

        echo_1 = BashOperator(task_id="echo_1", bash_command=f"echo {echo_message_1}")

        echo_2 = BashOperator(task_id="echo_2", bash_command=f"echo {echo_message_2}")

        echo_1 >> echo_2

    return dag_example()
```

**hello_world_dag.py**

```py
#airflow dag <- Make sure this these words appear _somewhere_ in the file.

from dag_template_module import dag_template

dag_template(dag_id="dag_example", echo_message_1="Hello", echo_message_2="World")
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, this will be invaluable.